# TI-84 Set Variable Based on Boolean Expression

Tags: ti-basic

For a ti-84 program I used the quadratic equation and stored the root with the plus sign as N and the root with the negative sign as R. I then want to only use the positive root as the value for the rest of the program (if both are positive it doesn't matter I just want to check one is positive), so I did as follows:

```
If N>0 --> U

ElseR-->U
```

But it didn't work. Is it not possible to use store as a command in an if-else statement? Or is there another way to only choose the positive variable and store that as U?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, listen. Blazo's answer is wrong. Every If statement that has an Else also needs a Then and an End. This is the correct way to write it without piecewise expressions (piecewise expressions are usually the best way to go, though, so I suggest you check out dohaqatar's answer as well):

```
If N>0
Then
N->U
Else
R->U
End
```

With two separate lone If's, you can reduce the size of the code by one byte to 17 bytes:

```
If N>0
N->U
If N<=0
R->U
```

You can compress it even more, saving 5 more bytes to make 12 bytes:

```
R->U
If N>0
N->U
```

You can also use a piecewise expression such as dohaqatar's below, also 12 bytes:

```
N<0:RAns+Nnot(Ans->U
```

The best part is, an algorithm change reduces code size to 6 bytes:

```
max(R,N->U
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be quite easily accomplished through your standard `If`, `Else` statements; however, A quicker way of doing this is through [piece-wise functions](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/piecewise-expressions). In TI-Basic, every Boolean expression evaluates to either `1` or `0`, representing true and false respectively. This fact can be exploited to make certain conditional expressions much shorter.

Your code using standard `If` `Else` syntax:

```
If N>0
Then
N→U
Else
R→U
End
```

This option is 18 bytes long.

Using piece-wise expressions, your code can be compressed to this:

```
N<0:RAns+Nnot(Ans→U
```

Resulting in a line of code only 12 bytes long.

Comment: An algorithm change to `max(R,N->U` might be better :D but I love your piecewise expression.

Comment: @Timtech I was about to comment on your answer about that. Clever solution to use `max(` like that. I noticed it has the added benefit of not throwing an error on complex numbers.

Comment: Yeah, after optimizing for a while, I never thought to come share it on SO before. I'm glad I did!